# How to automatically update one PHP class on several platforms?

Tags: php, github, repository, dry

Let's say I have a php class stored in a single file. If this class is used in several projects located on different hosts (or even by different users) it will be a big pain to update this class.

As I can imagine this could be done automatically by this routine:

1. PHP class (or file) stored in a single repository.
2. On each host using this class should be a cron job to test if this (these) class(es) (or files) have any update.
3. If YES this file is downloading and replacing existing one.

I could do all this my self but I suppose that there should be such ready-to-use solutions. My be existing repositories like github has such functionality or any other...

Questions:

1. Is the scenario I described above optimal for this functionality?
2. Is there any ready-to-use solutions? (hoping for free solution)

Comment: Could anyone explain what can be wrong with the question? Why it receives downvotes?

Comment: No homework done. Bad!

Answer (score 3):

We use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to manage our dependencies, which can load from private repositories. Develop your shared class inside of a project and then set it as a dependency of your downstream projects inside of `composer.json`. After updating your upstream project (that contains your shared files), your downstream projects can pull those changes in by just running `$ composer update`

You can set up downstream projects to point to your upstream project like this inside of `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "myname/myupstreamproject": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
         {
             "type": "git",
             "url": "git@github.com:myname/myproject.git"
         }
    ]
}
```

If you use tags on your repo, you can replace `"dev-master"` with the appropriate [versioning syntax](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md) if, for some reason, you need to have some of your projects using different versions of your shared files.

Answer (score 1):

check into using rsync.  rsync can be used to replicate files/folders across multiple systems and can be triggered from the source system to deploy the changes, if any (incremental).  Or, if the class is in github or other repository system, write an automated task that performs an update on a regular basis.